Error while Setting up sitecore serialization
Recently, I was trying to setup Sitecore Serialization for my Local Sitecore instance using Sitecore CLI.
In one of the steps, while trying to connect to a Sitecore instance, using the below command , I started getting the below error --
dotnet sitecore login --authority https://<Sitecore identity server> --cm https://<Sitecore instance> --allow-write true


Can anyone help me with above error. Thanks in advance.

Can you check https://{{IdentityServerHost}}/.well-known/openid-configuration is returning a valid json?

Yes ,it is returning valid json

The issue may be due to an expired or not trusted SSL certificate.
First thing , you could check if your identity server certificate is present under the trusted root certificate folder or not.
Also, get the certificate thumbprint, by running the following command :
 Get-ChildItem -path Cert:localmachine\My

Incase if the certificate is expired, try creating a new self-signed certificate, either through IIS or PowerShell.
In IIS Manager, select your identity server site, go to Bindings, and update the HTTPS binding to use the new certificate.
This should help re-establish a secure connection with the updated SSL certificate.
Hope this helps you!

By Changing Certificate in IIS binding, it is working.
Thanks for help

You can run below command from the Sitecore Identity server to get more details on the exception.
dotnet Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.dll

Based on the error you shared, it looks like the certificate thumbprint is not valid inside the file Config\production\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml in the identity server. It should point to the certificate thumprint on the Sitecore Identity Server.

You can get certificate thumbprint for the identity server by running below command. Based on the identity server name, you can get the value of certificate thumbprint and update on the above file.
Get-ChildItem -path Cert:localmachine\My

Lastly make sure this certificate is under the trusted certificate folder and is not expired.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any queries.

Check it in your solution under \.sitecore folder and see the user.json file if the below entries have https: with your instance name.
"host": "https://sc10sc.dev.local",
"authority": "https://sc10identityserver.dev.local"

If not, update with according to above and check again.
Next thing you can check the certificate named $SitecoreSiteName.pfx need to move under trusted root certificate folder. It may be an issue with untrusted certificate.
It should solve the issue.
Hope it helps.
